# Is there a way to hide the label display for the first and the last data sets, Highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have this

jsfiddle.net/4vzEt/21/

Where in I do not want to show the tooltip for the first set (ie., if the user hover on week 0) and the last set (ie., if the user hover on week 7) .

I know the option like http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#plotOptions-series--enableMouseTracking

But it will hide it for all, I need to hide only for the first and last series of data.

Please help me.